# What is the purpose of using packages like flutter_screenutil in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I understand that Flutter uses **logical pixels** for sizing, which convert to physical pixels at a ratio specified by the specific device the Flutter application is running on. Therefore my question is what is the purpose of libraries like [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil), and why is this one in particular so popular?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use `flutter_screenutil` and similar tools.  Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/

Comment: very helpful, also we can not use const because of flutter_screenutil

Comment: You actually can't ever use const with layout decisions.  Consider a desktop or web app.  They can change size with no notice.

Answer (score 7):

You asked 'what is the purpose of libraries like flutter_screenutil' and accepted an answer that just said don't use it, with a link to why you shouldn't. The issue here is that not every single app needs to be, or can be, responsive in the way of the linked article.

For instance, in the linked article, a set of chips appear as rows of 4 and 3 on the small screen, but adapts responsively as one row of 7 on the larger screen. In the context of that app, this is entirely correct design and I support the approach listed there, and the reasons listed there for that approach.

But it isn't absolute - it's only applicable to certain types of apps. I ask you to consider a little-known app called Candy Crush. If a level has an 8x12 grid of candies on a portrait iPhone 6 screen, should it be 'responsive' and show a grid of 24 x 4 candies on a landscape iPad screen? Obviously not, it still needs to present an 8x12 grid no matter the screen size or orientation. Additionally, whilst it could maintain the same physical size on a larger screen, it would look very odd that way, lost in an island of a black surround!

Apps like Candy Crush that have a 'fixed' layout handle this by scaling it to fit the viewport of the device it is presented on. So to answer your question, this is why libraries such as flutter_screenutil are useful to help you achieve that, for that particular app design pattern.

Is that library being used appropriately in every instance by a developer? Probably not, there will definitely be cases where that library is used as a shortcut to avoid a thoughtful responsive design that Flutter is more than capable of giving you. And even in the Candy Crush example, you could still mix and match responsive with scaling, such as a different layout based upon the device orientation, etc.

We should always have a varied set of tools available to us as developers, and be wary if someone says we should only use one specific tool. If you only have a hammer, everything looks like a nail but conversely, those who only deal with nails will tell you to only use a hammer.

Comment: good point, great explanation

Comment: I concur, particularly the part about gamefields having special layout logic.  But for the most part, we're not building games. We're building presentation of and interaction with varying amounts of information into a dimension-provided portal.

Answer (score 1):

The `flutter_screenutil` package takes into account the size of screen from the UI prototyping tool (such as Figma), while the regular Flutter sizing doesn't have access to that information.

For example, take a look at the package's implementation, in [`lib/src/screen_util.dart`](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil/blob/master/lib/src/screen_util.dart) you can find this code:

```dart
double get scaleWidth => screenWidth / _uiSize.width;
```

The ratio of the actual screen width to the UI design width is used to scale the width used in the implementation.

The screen dimension from the UI prototyping tool is given by the user at the [initialization](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil#initialize-and-set-the-fit-size-and-font-size-to-scale-according-to-the-systems-font-size-accessibility-option):

```dart
ScreenUtilInit(
  designSize: const Size(360, 690), // the screen dimension from Figma
  ...
)
```

Comment: What has Figma/any other prototyping tool have to do with this? I don't need to convert a Figma prototype to Flutter.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with converting Figma to Flutter. But a usually Flutter developers see the UI design prototype in Figma and use that as a guideline to how they size a widget. For example, if a developer sees a widget in Figma that is of size 20 x 30 inside a screen of size 25 x 35, of course the button should appear big and takes up many of the screen space (this is what the designer wants). This can be achieved by simply setting the widget with parameters like `width: 20.w, height: 30.h`, and the package will already know how to scale it to the screen size correctly.

Comment: With regular Flutter sizing, of course setting `width: 20, height: 30` will result a very small widget compared to the screen on most devices.